# How to open and maintain a modifiable buffer in bash

Tags: bash, files

I currently have a script that I am using multiple functions to do my own smaller templating system upon that pulls various configurations from a configs directory. I understand that this is an admittedly more extensive use of a bash script that most would push for me to use python or another scripting language in. On to the problem:

I have a bunch of functions like so

```bsh
a() {}
b() {}
c() {}
...
```

and what I want to do is define a global constant that is responsible for containing an open buffer. This is such that when one of these functions begins modifying the configuration via a read loop I can pass off some of the logic to other functions in charge of the templating system (using the format `# % filename.to.use.as.a.template.conf % #`) while still using the same buffer. I know I could create a temporary file and write my configuration there *first* then use `mv` to overwrite, but I am attempting to avoid this.

Ideally the logic flow goes like so:

> Function "A" is doing some logic working on the configuration and then it runs into a tag '# % example.conf % #` it then will call function "B", which is in charge of loading templating which looks up the buffer function "A" was working on and appends the template contents 'example.conf' to the buffer and then hands it back off to "A" which then jumps to the end of the inserted text and continues parsing the file.

Example pseudo code implementation:

```bsh
install_template() {
  local TEMPLATE_FILE
  TEMPLATE_FILE = "${1}"
  write_to_buffer "$(cat "${TEMPLATE_FILE}")" # This where I'm hung up at :/
}


while read -r line; do
  if [[ line = *#*%*%*#*]]; then
    install_template "${line}"
  fi
done < "${CONFIGURATION}" > "${SOME_BUFFER}"
```

The issue with the above pseudo code is that I *could* echo the output from cat in the `install_template` function, but then the issue is that my echo gets captured by the read loop and output to the buffer, ideally I'd be able to still log what's going on to `STDOUT` without it *all* getting captured by the read loop.

Is there a good way of doing this or a way to at least track the buffer that A is working on, e,g via a global variable or maybe another function to write to that buffer without capturing `STDOUT`?

Comment: What is `write_to_buffer` meant to write to? On one hand, it looks like you want it to write to the file whose name is in `$SOME_BUFFER` (_"... function "B", ... looks up the buffer function "A" was working on and appends the template contents ... to the buffer ... hands it back off to "A" which then jumps to the end of the inserted text ..."_). On the other hand, you say that _"the issue is that my echo gets captured by the read loop and output to the buffer"_, as if you didn't want `write_to_buffer` to write to the `$SOME_BUFFER` file. Maybe it's just me, but... can you please clarify?